# How do i gather dates from different columns and put them all into 1 column?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, mutate

I´ve taken data from Superligaen which is a football league in Denmark. When open up my the data frame I´ve gotten from the url the rounds are separated into different columns together with the date the game have been played. How do i merge all the dates into 1 column instead of the 33 columns/round they are in now?

Here's a photo of how the dataframe looks:

[image]

Here's a photo of how i want i to look:

[image]

I'm quite new to this so I haven't tried much other than asking ChatGPT.

Data:

```
> dput(head(sason_07_08_super, 20))
structure(list(`Runde 1...1` = c("Ons", "Ons", "Ons", "Ons", 
"Ons", "Ons", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), `Runde 1...2` = c("18/07 18.00", "18/07 18.00", "18/07 20.00", 
"18/07 20.00", "25/07 20.00", "08/08 20.00", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...3 = c("FCN-FCK", 
"RFC-VFF", "EFB-BIF", "AGF-ACH", "OB-LBK", "FCM-AaB", "BIF-FCN", 
"VFF-EFB", "LBK-RFC", "AGF-OB", "ACH-FCM", "AaB-FCK", "FCK-VFF", 
"OB-ACH", "FCN-LBK", "FCM-BIF", "EFB-AGF", "RFC-AaB", "AGF-FCK", 
"EFB-RFC"), ...4 = c("1-0", "2-0", "1-0", "1-2", "1-1", "2-1", 
"2-2", "0-5", "0-3", "0-2", "2-1", "1-1", "3-1", "3-3", "0-1", 
"5-0", "2-2", "5-0", "0-1", "1-3"), ...5 = c(9.045, 5.851, 11.008, 
12.562, 7.598, 7.665, 9.865, 3.164, 1.631, 7.662, 2.149, 9.784, 
12.337, 6.541, 5.065, 10.137, 8.845, 8.889, 13.217, 8.502), ...6 = c("Henning Jensen", 
"Henrik Kragh", "Anders Hermansen", "Jesper Overgaard", "Emil Laursen", 
"Claus Bo Larsen", "Anders Hermansen", "Henning Jensen", "Thomas Vejlgaard", 
"Henrik Priegel", "Lars Christoffersen", "Nicolai Vollquartz", 
"Michael Svendsen", "Michael Johansen", "Jesper Overgaard*", 
"Nicolai Vollquartz", "Henrik Kragh", "Emil Laursen", "Claus Bo Larsen", 
"Michael Svendsen"), ...7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Runde 2...1` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Lør", "Søn", "Søn", "Søn", "Man", "Ons", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Runde 2...2` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "21/07 17.00", "22/07 14.00", "22/07 16.00", "22/07 18.00", 
"23/07 19.00", "25/07 18.00", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `Runde 3...1` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "Lør", "Søn", "Søn", "Søn", "Man", "Ons", NA, 
    NA), `Runde 3...2` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "28/07 17.00", "29/07 14.00", "29/07 16.00", 
    "29/07 18.00", "30/07 19.00", "01/08 20.00", NA, NA), `Runde 4...1` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "Lør", "Søn"), `Runde 4...2` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "04/08 17.00", 
    "05/08 14.00"), `Runde 5...1` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 5...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 6...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 6...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 7...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 7...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 8...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 8...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 9...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 9...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 10...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 10...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 11...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 11...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 12...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 12...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 13...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 13...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 14...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 14...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 15...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 15...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 16...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 16...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 17...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 17...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 18...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 18...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 19...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 19...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 20...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 20...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 21...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 21...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 22...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 22...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 23...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 23...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 24...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 24...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 25...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 25...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 26...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 26...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 27...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 27...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 28...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 28...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 29...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 29...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 30...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 30...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 31...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 31...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 32...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 32...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 33...1` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `Runde 33...2` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: hi aagerbo! welcome to SO! Can you include some data? Run `dput` on your dataframe, and add edit your question to add the result. If it is too large, and it gives you an error, just do it for however many rows you can, e.g. `dput(head(df, 20))`

Comment: Hi Mark. I hope this gives you a better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1. We create an id column (not strictly necessary, but good practice, given you don't have a primary key
2. We pivot the data longer, parsing the Runde column names into their number, and then their column number within each Runde. We then get a Runde column, with the Runde number, and the columns `1` and `2`, which have the day of the week, and the date and time in plain text.

You could leave it there with this, and just select the columns you want to use. But as an exercise, this is what I would do, to make the data tidy:

3. Separate the match column into a home team and an away team column, which will make it much easier to use down the road
4. Do the same with the score data
5. As just splitting the score data column into two doesn't change the fact that they're still columns of strings, we need to mutate them to transform them into integer columns so we can perform arithmetic on them
6. Give the attendance column a name, and give it in the correct units
7. Give the referee column a name
8. Parse the date time column into a date time format, which is much easier to work with
9. Drop the columns we used, but no longer need, such as `...6`
10. Drop the day of the week column `1` and the column of NAs `...7`

```
df |> 
  mutate(id = row_number()) |>
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Runde"), names_pattern = "Runde (\\d+)...(\\d+)", names_to = c("Runde", ".value"), values_drop_na = TRUE) |>
  separate_wider_delim(col = `...3`, names = c("Hjemmehold", "Udehold"), delim = "-") |>
  separate_wider_delim(col = `...4`, names = c("Hjemmeholdsmål", "Udeholdsmål"), delim = "-") |>
  mutate(across(c(Hjemmeholdsmål, Udeholdsmål), as.integer),
        Tilstedeværelse = `...5` * 1000,
         Dommer = `...6`,
         datotid = as.POSIXct(`2`, format = "%d/%m %H.%M", tz = "Europe/Copenhagen"),
         .keep = "unused") |>
         select(-`...7`, -`1`)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 20 × 9
   Hjemmehold Udehold Hjemmeholdsmål Udeholdsmål    id Runde Tilstedeværelse
   <chr>      <chr>            <int>       <int> <int> <chr>           <dbl>
 1 FCN        FCK                  1           0     1 1                9045
 2 RFC        VFF                  2           0     2 1                5851
 3 EFB        BIF                  1           0     3 1               11008
 4 AGF        ACH                  1           2     4 1               12562
 5 OB         LBK                  1           1     5 1                7598
 6 FCM        AaB                  2           1     6 1                7665
 7 BIF        FCN                  2           2     7 2                9865
 8 VFF        EFB                  0           5     8 2                3164
 9 LBK        RFC                  0           3     9 2                1631
10 AGF        OB                   0           2    10 2                7662
11 ACH        FCM                  2           1    11 2                2149
12 AaB        FCK                  1           1    12 2                9784
13 FCK        VFF                  3           1    13 3               12337
14 OB         ACH                  3           3    14 3                6541
15 FCN        LBK                  0           1    15 3                5065
16 FCM        BIF                  5           0    16 3               10137
17 EFB        AGF                  2           2    17 3                8845
18 RFC        AaB                  5           0    18 3                8889
19 AGF        FCK                  0           1    19 4               13217
20 EFB        RFC                  1           3    20 4                8502
   Dommer              datotid            
   <chr>               <dttm>             
 1 Henning Jensen      2023-07-18 18:00:00
 2 Henrik Kragh        2023-07-18 18:00:00
 3 Anders Hermansen    2023-07-18 20:00:00
 4 Jesper Overgaard    2023-07-18 20:00:00
 5 Emil Laursen        2023-07-25 20:00:00
 6 Claus Bo Larsen     2023-08-08 20:00:00
 7 Anders Hermansen    2023-07-21 17:00:00
 8 Henning Jensen      2023-07-22 14:00:00
 9 Thomas Vejlgaard    2023-07-22 16:00:00
10 Henrik Priegel      2023-07-22 18:00:00
11 Lars Christoffersen 2023-07-23 19:00:00
12 Nicolai Vollquartz  2023-07-25 18:00:00
13 Michael Svendsen    2023-07-28 17:00:00
14 Michael Johansen    2023-07-29 14:00:00
15 Jesper Overgaard*   2023-07-29 16:00:00
16 Nicolai Vollquartz  2023-07-29 18:00:00
17 Henrik Kragh        2023-07-30 19:00:00
18 Emil Laursen        2023-08-01 20:00:00
19 Claus Bo Larsen     2023-08-04 17:00:00
20 Michael Svendsen    2023-08-05 14:00:00
```